# VS Code not excluding Code's node_modules from being watched - file watch limit reached

Tags: visual-studio-code, inotify

In VS Code, I have a Vue project with less than 50 files but upon running the dev server VS Code throws `Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached`.

My **VS Code Watcher Exclude settings** have the following ignore patterns.

```
**/.git/objects/**
**/.git/subtree-cache/**
**/node_modules/**
```

I tried to figure out what files could possibly be setting me over the [max_user_watches](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc) limit on my machine, which is 8192.

With a [StackExchange answer from user "mosvy"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501952) and a [script derived from that answer](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/master/utils/scripts/inotify-consumers) by another user "oligofren", I've found that the following sources are likely causing this.

```
| Watchers | Source                                                                                                                   |
| -------- | ------                                                                                                                   |
| 4033     | /usr/share/code/code --max-old-space-size=3072 /usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsse |
| 3889     | /usr/share/code/code /usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/typingsInstaller.js --globalTy |
| 99       | /usr/share/code/code /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/bootstrap-fork --type=watcherService                              |
```

I'm not sure why any of these are being watched, but the first two seem to be ignoring VS Code's Watcher Exclude setting of `**/node_modules/**`

**If possible, is it safe to exclude all three of these in the Watcher Exclude settings of VS Code?**

I don't want to break my VS Code install.

### Update

The Watcher Exclude settings above are what VS Code has listed as default. I added the same settings

```
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.git/objects/**": true,
    "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
    "**/node_modules/**": true
  }
```

directly to the settings.json file and the two node_modules sources listed above were removed and the error went away for that session.

After restarting VS Code and verifying that settings.json still included the changes I made, the two node_modules sources from before are no longer being excluded.

Comment: @GinoMempin Thank you, but I'm glad I didn't. The "solution" proved to not work after all, and this way I'm not leading anyone astray.

Comment: I edited the update section to hopefully be less confusing.

Comment: 8192 is way too few inotify listeners. No reason not to increase it to 500K on a modern system.

Comment: Just linking this, https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40898 but unfortunately it is closed.  I'm still experiencing this problem and it is late 2022.  I'm going to up the limit, but it is stupid that the node_modules cannot be excluded.

Comment: The trick for me was deleting node_modules after adding the entry to vscode settings and finally restarting vscode.

Answer (score -3):

If feasible, you could disable the built-in extension: **TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features**, but that would remove some features that might take away the whole point of using vscode.

Comment: Or just uninstall VS Code altogether and go outside

Comment: it is not the worst idea